# R: estVar and cor

Tags: r, correlation, multivariate-analysis

I have a problem when estimating a multivariate Regression Model.

I know that `cor(y1, y2)` is strongly positive but when I am trying to estimate a regression model like

```
x <- lm(cbind(y1, y2) ~ X)
```

then `estvar(x)` returns a slightly negative covariance. Is that possible and why? I can´t explain it to myself.

Answer (score 5):

The probable reason is that the strong correlation between y1 and y2 is caused by x. Imagine you have a data set of children aged between 6 and 12. Then you will find a strong correlation between height and reading skill. However, this is not really because higher people are generally smarter, but because they are both strongly influenced in the same direction by a common factor, which is age.

The function estVar gives you the variance matrix for the residuals, which means the error term which are not explained by x. In the example above you will see that when you regress both reading skill and height over age that the correlation will disappear in the residuals, since the factor that induces that correlation is accounted for.

In fact, this phenomen is one of the main reasons why it is critical to control for confounders.

Comment: Thank you, that helps and is consistent to two seperate OLS-regressions